Updating several data sources in a single transaction
Using Spring Boot, I need to read and update data from 2 different data sources. For this I have configured my application based on https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources and https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation
Reading from the 2 data sources is working fine, but when trying to update, the following error appears:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query

What is incorrect or missing?
How to update all data sources in the same transaction?
The whole source code is:
datasource 1:
com/example/jpa/db1/entity/Db1Table1Entity.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1", catalog = "db1")
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Db1Table1Entity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "a")
  private String a;

  @Column(name = "b")
  private String b;
}

com/example/jpa/db1/repo/Db1Table1Repository.java
@Repository
public interface Db1Table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Db1Table1Entity, String> {

  Optional<Db1Table1Entity> findByA(final String a);

  @Modifying
  @Query("UPDATE Db1Table1Entity e SET e.b = :b WHERE e.a = :a")
  void updateByA(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
}

com/example/jpa/db1/Db1JpaConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.example.jpa.db1.repo"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db1TransactionManager")
public class Db1JpaConfiguration {

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory(
      final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, final DataSource db1DataSource) {

    return builder
        .dataSource(db1DataSource)
        .packages("com.example.jpa.db1")
        .persistenceUnit("db1")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db1")
  public DataSourceProperties db1DataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db1.hikari")
  public DataSource db1xDataSource() {
    return db1DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager db1TransactionManager(
      final EntityManagerFactory db1EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db1EntityManagerFactory);
  }
}

datasource 2:
com/example/jpa/db2/entity/Db2Table1Entity.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "table1", catalog = "db2")
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Accessors(fluent = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class Db2Table1Entity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "a")
  private String a;

  @Column(name = "b")
  private String b;
}

com/example/jpa/db2/repo/Db2Table1Repository.java
@Repository
public interface Db2Table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Db2Table1Entity, String> {

  Optional<Db2Table1Entity> findByA(final String a);

  @Modifying
  @Query("UPDATE Db2Table1Entity e SET e.b = :b WHERE e.a = :a")
  void updateByA(@Param("a") String a, @Param("b") String b);
}

com/example/jpa/db2/Db2JpaConfiguration.java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = {"com.example.jpa.db2.repo"},
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager")
public class Db2JpaConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory(
      final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, final DataSource db2DataSource) {

    return builder
        .dataSource(db2DataSource)
        .packages("com.example.jpa.db2")
        .persistenceUnit("db2")
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db2")
  public DataSourceProperties db2DataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db2.hikari")
  public DataSource db2DataSource() {
    return db2DataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(
      final EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
  }
}

service:
com/example/jpa/DbService.java
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class DbService {
  private final Db1Table1Repository repo1;
  private final Db2Table1Repository repo2;

  public DbService(Db1Table1Repository repo1, Db2Table1Repository repo2) {
    this.repo1 = repo1;
    this.repo2 = repo2;
  }

  public List<String> find(final String a) {
    return List.of(
        repo1.findByA(a).map(Db1Table1Entity::b).orElse(""),
        repo2.findByA(a).map(Db2Table1Entity::b).orElse(""));
  }

  @Transactional
  public void update(final String a, final String b) {
    repo1.updateByA(a, b);
    repo2.updateByA(a, b);
  }
}

test data:
INSERT
IGNORE INTO
        db1.table1(
            a,
            b
        )
    VALUES(
        "info-a1",
        "info-b1"
    ),
    (
        "info-a2",
        "info-b2"
    );
INSERT
IGNORE INTO
        db2.table1(
            a,
            b
        )
    VALUES(
        "info-a1",
        "info-b1"
    ),
    (
        "info-a2",
        "info-b2"
    );

tests:
@DataJpaTest(properties = "spring.test.database.replace=NONE")
@Isolated
@Import(value = {DbService.class, Db1JpaConfiguration.class, Db2JpaConfiguration.class})
class DbServiceIT {
  @Autowired private DbService sut;

  public static Stream<Arguments> data() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of("info-a1", List.of("info-b1", "info-b1")),
        Arguments.of("info-a2", List.of("info-b2", "info-b2")),
        Arguments.of("xxx-yyy", List.of("", "")));
  }

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("data")
  void find(final String a, final List<String> expected) {
    final var result = sut.find(a);
    Assertions.assertThat(result).containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(expected);
  }

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("data")
  void update(final String a, final List<String> expected) {
    final var newValue = "new info";
    sut.update(a, newValue);

    final var result = sut.find(a);
    Assertions.assertThat(result).hasSameSizeAs(expected).allMatch(r -> r.equals(newValue));
  }
}


I removed you side-questions. Questions must be about one thing and one thing only.

What package does that @Transactional annotation come from? The simplest answer to this problem is that while you think a transaction is active, there really isn't one.

The following import is used: import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

Darn, that is the correct one. Just to note, the article you link to indeed documents how to define multiple datasources in your application but that does not imply those datasources can be part of the same transaction. This generally involves setting up a distributed transaction (or "two phase commit"), using XA datasources. I.E, this magic: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/io/jta.html .

I believe you are using local transaction management whereas you need global transaction management. I've not done anything similar myself so can't give you a more complete answer but looking at this might be a good place to start: https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee
